# LDAP query for memberOf in settings

Tags: ldap

I am setting up a software package to work with our LDAP server. Since we have limited licenses, I need to limit what group a user can be a member of to be included. I have a field called *LDAP Search Base* where I can specify something like this:

```
(sAMAccountName={0})
```

The `{0}` is filled in with the login name. I would like to limit the users to be part of our Development LDAP group, but the `memberOf` group can have multiple values, Doing something like this:

```
(&(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=*Development*))
```

doesn't work.

Is there a way to query LDAP to specify that I am looking through all of the values of `memberOf` looking for a groups that matches `*Development*`?

Comment: That should work, slowly, but you could also enumerate all the possible values in a |-subfilter.

Comment: I can't do a subfilter. When I use a Perl program, I can use a subfilter, but this is a web form. Plus, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't see why you can't use a sub filter just because it's a Web form. "Doesn't seem to work" doesn't convey any useful information.

Comment: There's not much to report except that when I do the above query, no users are returned, even if I set the group to just an asterisk. There's no log to that shows what the query is doing. If I leave out the memberOf clause, users are returned. We have a weekly meeting with the provider, so I'll ask about it there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `memberOf` is a Distinguished name. Substring matches using wildcards are not supported on DNs